# JPA repository read, delete and save Object with old id

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to read `Pricebject` ID from repository, delete it and save it as new `PriceObject` again with old ID, but it saves with different ID.

This is my method:

```
public void getActualPricesAndSaveInDb() {

        try {
                String symbolString = symbol.getSymbol();
                PriceObject oldPriceObject = pricesRepository.findByCompanySymbol(symbolString);
                PriceObject newPriceObject = new PriceObject();
                if (oldPriceObject != null) {
                    pricesRepository.deleteByCompanySymbol(symbolString); 
                    newPriceObject.setId(oldPriceObject.getId());
                }
                newPriceObject.setCompanySymbol(symbolString);
                pricesRepository.save(newPriceObject);
        } catch (APICommandConstructionException | APIReplyParseException | APICommunicationException
                | APIErrorResponse e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my **PriceObject.class**:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class PriceObject {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String companySymbol;

    ...
}
```

I've tried so far:

> - change annotation `@GeneratedValue` parameter for `(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`,
> - change annotation `@GeneratedValue` parameter for `(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`.

Comment: Whats the logic behind this? Why deleting and creating an object? Why not just updating the existing?

Comment: @Daniel That's true I've changed for just creating new one, if not exist or update.

Comment: That's the better way. And it created less load on your database. A delete is a pretty expensive operation in a database.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `id` directly using the entity won't work if you specify a strategy for generating the `id`.
To set the `id` of the entity you want you have two solution (not all possible solution by the way):

1. Remove the `@GeneratedValue` annotation from your `id` field, but if you do this you have to supply an `id` for each entity you want to save.
2. Create a native query directly using the `EntityManager`.

   entityManager.createNativeQuery("insert into table(id, ...) values (id,...)");

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem correctly but it might be due to the generated value. Maybe you could try deleting that annotation if you don't need it for any other method, or changing it with this one:  `@Column(unique = true)`.